# Why separate methods for mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps?

Tags: redux

I'm writing a redux app and I ran in to a small but nagging question. Why is the convention to separate the mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps methods? Why not just have one:

```
mapToProps = (state, dispatch) => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `mapDispatchToProps` doesn't need to be recompiled when the state change (it's only called once).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in below link

> The separation exists for performance reasons: **mapStateToProps** and
>   **mapDispatchToProps** are separate for a good reason, consider the
>   performance: mapStateToProps is actually run several times when state
>   changes, and mapDispatchToProps once (or way fewer anyway than
>   mapStateToProps) it doesn't depend on the state.

[Discussion](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/321#issuecomment-197941829)